# Advice for submitting to audio sharing sites for backlinks

Tags: seo, link-building

I am working on getting some backlinks to our site. I came across a blog discussing ways to get backlinks and this was one of the tips. The idea is to **submit real audio tracks that I custom made** (not making giberish sounds or copying someones sound) **to audio sharing sites** whether it’s free or for stock purchase.

What do you think of this strategy? Is it worth the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about scoring backlinks from audio submission, but whatever you do, just make sure that the sources you use are very reliable.

For example, having links to your site from actual banks or other big businesses that have served customers for years or even from websites that have an excellent reputation on the net is very good.

Having links to your site from people or companies you don't know or as a result of doing something small for a random company might not go well because those kinds of sources might change for the worse in the future.

Whatever you do, make sure you can actually *trust* the source before using it.

Because I don't know details surrounding this audio site you talk about, my answer is probably the best answer you're gonna get.

Comment: I didn't have an audio site in mind. I was just asking about the practice itself and if it mattered the type of site I am getting a link from (because I am not in the audio industry) and if that mattered. I would need to research if there are audio sites that allow do follow links and find out if they have good website authority.